# Unable to Install MULE EE Service The Specified Service already exists (0x411)

Tags: mulesoft, mule-esb, mule4

I have a windows VM and there is already Mule EE server setup using the amc setup command and able to see the server on Runtime Manager as Running.

Now when i install another Mule EE on the same Windows VM (different folder) , when i say mule.install it says
[image]

```
"Unable to Install MULE EE Service  The Specified Service already exists (0x411)"
```

Anything to consider for installing multiple server on same Windows VM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that you are installing to another directory, but that both instances are trying to use the same Windows Service name. The default is `mule`.

Before trying to install the second instance you have to edit the conf/wrapper.conf configuration file and change the service name it will try to use:

```
wrapper.ntservice.name=mule2
```

Reference: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-can-I-create-a-uniquely-named-Windows-service-for-each-Mule-instance

Comment: one more question to the following topic. on VM Machine is there a way that i can set like for runtime1 use 60% of cpu and runtime2 use 40% of cpu ?

Comment: That's a different question and really a different topic too.